# Request rejected if MVC controller action called twice simultaneously

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, file-upload

I am new to MVC and I have a controller that has the following Actions:

- Index
- FileUpload

For `FileUpload` we upload big files to be filled in the database, in this function many database calls occur (Create and Delete).

I have noticed that when 2 users call `FileUpload` at the same time, 1 of the requests gets rejected and the user needs to upload the file again.
How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: When you say rejected what code is returned to the client (400's,500's)?

Comment: Hi Alex, 500's, this happens when i try to update the database records (add or update) is there anyway to queue the requests  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code that fills the database is probably causing dead-locks (locking same tables), and most likely an exception is thrown causing a 500 http status code. 
(Your filling code tries to change same db row, causing a dead-lock and the second attempt to fail)

Comment: And what is the solution in this case ? Is there anyway to queue the mesaages ?

Comment: You could code some re-try logic, if the file fails once try to process it again and again until success. Or if you can implement a queue on back-end, and process the files one by one as queue messages, are you using Windows Azure cloud (if so you can upload the files as blobs, and generate a queue message for each one, you will need an azure worker role that will process the queue messages one by one, this an expensive solution but a reliable one)?

Comment: Thanks Andrei, this helped